# Xampp MySQL shutdown unexpectedly (problem is not the port)

Tags: mysql, xampp

So, last night I turned off my computer, and this morning as I tried to start MySQL through the Xampp Control Panel I got the infamous "Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly."

[image]

I know that this has already been asked before but I've searched for solutions (up to the third page of Google results!) and nothing works.
So far I've tried:
- deleting mysql/data/ibdata1 file
- changing the port (even though I checked and there is nothing working on port 3306, nothing workling on port 3*** at all)
- restarting
- mysql_upgrade
- praying
- starting as Administrator
- checking if the mysql service is disabled from Services (it was not)
- checking if there is another MySQL installed on the machine (connected to the port solution) - there is nothing else installed except the Xampp.

Log file:

```
2020-05-19 12:22:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-05-19 12:22:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-05-19 12:22:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-05-19 12:22:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-05-19 12:22:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-05-19 12:22:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2020-05-19 12:22:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-05-19 12:22:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-05-19 12:22:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-05-19 12:22:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-05-19 12:22:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-05-19 12:22:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-05-19 12:22:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.6 started; log sequence number 113899; transaction id 9
2020-05-19 12:22:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2020-05-19 12:22:33 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-05-19 12:22:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200519 12:22:33
2020-05-19 12:22:33 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2020-05-19 12:22:33 6 [Warning] Failed to load slave replication state from table mysql.gtid_slave_pos: 1932: Table 'mysql.gtid_slave_pos' doesn't exist in engine
2020-05-19 12:22:33 7 [Note] Reading Master_info: 'master-2020@002d03@002d16@002014@003a08@003a15@00200@0020@005bnote@005d@0020reading@0020of@0020all@0020master_info@0020entries@0020succeeded@000d.info'  Relay_info:'relay-log-2020@002d03@002d16@002014@003a08@003a15@00200@0020@005bnote@005d@0020reading@0020of@0020all@0020master_info@0020entries@0020succeeded@000d.info'
2020-05-19 12:22:33 7 [Warning] Neither --relay-log nor --relay-log-index were used; so replication may break when this MySQL server acts as a slave and has his hostname changed!! Please use '--log-basename=#' or '--relay-log=mysql-relay-bin' to avoid this problem.
2020-05-19 12:22:33 7 [Note] Initialized Master_info from 'master-2020@002d03@002d16@002014@003a08@003a15@00200@0020@005bnote@005d@0020reading@0020of@0020all@0020master_info@0020entries@0020succeeded@000d.info'
2020-05-19 12:22:33 7 [Note] Added new Master_info '2020-03-16 14:08:15 0 [Note] Reading of all Master_info entries succeeded
' to hash table
2020-05-19 12:22:33 7 [Note] Started replication for '2020-03-16 14:08:15 0 [Note] Reading of all Master_info entries succeeded
'
2020-05-19 12:22:33 8 [ERROR] Master '2020-03-16 14:08:15 0 [Note] Reading of all Master_info entries succeeded
': Slave I/O: Unable to load replication GTID slave state from mysql.gtid_slave_pos: Table 'mysql.gtid_slave_pos' doesn't exist in engine, Internal MariaDB error code: 1932
2020-05-19 12:22:33 9 [Note] Master '2020-03-16 14:08:15 0 [Note] Reading of all Master_info entries succeeded
': Slave SQL thread initialized, starting replication in log 'FIRST' at position 0, relay log '.\mysql-relay-bin-2020@002d03@002d16@002014@003a08@003a15@00200@0020@005bnote@005d@0020reading@0020of@0020all@0020master_info@0020entries@0020succeeded@000d.000001' position: 4
2020-05-19 12:22:33 7 [Note] Reading Master_info: 'master-2020@002d03@002d16@002014@003a08@003a15@00200@0020@005bnote@005d@0020added@0020new@0020master_info@0020@0027@0027@0020to@0020hash@0020table@000d.info'  Relay_info:'relay-log-2020@002d03@002d16@002014@003a08@003a15@00200@0020@005bnote@005d@0020added@0020new@0020master_info@0020@0027@0027@0020to@0020hash@0020table@000d.info'
2020-05-19 12:22:33 9 [ERROR] Master '2020-03-16 14:08:15 0 [Note] Reading of all Master_info entries succeeded
': Slave SQL: Unable to load replication GTID slave state from mysql.gtid_slave_pos: Table 'mysql.gtid_slave_pos' doesn't exist in engine, Internal MariaDB error code: 1932
2020-05-19 12:22:33 8 [Note] Master '2020-03-16 14:08:15 0 [Note] Reading of all Master_info entries succeeded
': Slave I/O thread: Start asynchronous replication to master '@:3306' in log '' at position 4
2020-05-19 12:22:33 8 [ERROR] Master '2020-03-16 14:08:15 0 [Note] Reading of all Master_info entries succeeded
': Slave I/O: Fatal error: Invalid (empty) username when attempting to connect to the master server. Connection attempt terminated. Internal MariaDB error code: 1593
2020-05-19 12:22:33 8 [Note] Master '2020-03-16 14:08:15 0 [Note] Reading of all Master_info entries succeeded
': Slave I/O thread killed while connecting to master
2020-05-19 12:22:33 8 [Note] Master '2020-03-16 14:08:15 0 [Note] Reading of all Master_info entries succeeded
': Slave I/O thread exiting, read up to log 'FIRST', position 4
2020-05-19 12:22:33 7 [Note] Initialized Master_info from 'master-2020@002d03@002d16@002014@003a08@003a15@00200@0020@005bnote@005d@0020added@0020new@0020master_info@0020@0027@0027@0020to@0020hash@0020table@000d.info'
2020-05-19 12:22:33 7 [Note] Added new Master_info '2020-03-16 14:08:15 0 [Note] Added new Master_info '' to hash table
' to hash table
2020-05-19 12:22:33 7 [Note] Started replication for '2020-03-16 14:08:15 0 [Note] Added new Master_info '' to hash table
'
2020-05-19 12:22:33 11 [Note] Master '2020-03-16 14:08:15 0 [Note] Added new Master_info '' to hash table
': Slave SQL thread initialized, starting replication in log 'FIRST' at position 0, relay log '.\mysql-relay-bin-2020@002d03@002d16@002014@003a08@003a15@00200@0020@005bnote@005d@0020added@0020new@0020master_info@0020@0027@0027@0020to@0020hash@0020table@000d.000001' position: 4
2020-05-19 12:22:33 7 [Note] Reading Master_info: 'master-2020@002d03@002d16@002014@003a08@003a15@00200@0020@005bnote@005d@0020c@003a@005cxampp@005cmysql@005cbin@005cmysqld@002eexe@003a@0020ready@0020for@0020connections@002e@000d.info'  Relay_info:'relay-log-2020@002d03@002d16@002014@003a08@003a15@00200@0020@005bnote@005d@0020c@003a@005cxampp@005cmysql@005cbin@005cmysqld@002eexe@003a@0020ready@0020for@0020connections@002e@000d.info'
2020-05-19 12:22:33 10 [ERROR] Master '2020-03-16 14:08:15 0 [Note] Added new Master_info '' to hash table
': Slave I/O: Unable to load replication GTID slave state from mysql.gtid_slave_pos: Table 'mysql.gtid_slave_pos' doesn't exist in engine, Internal MariaDB error code: 1932
2020-05-19 12:22:33 11 [ERROR] Master '2020-03-16 14:08:15 0 [Note] Added new Master_info '' to hash table
': Slave SQL: Unable to load replication GTID slave state from mysql.gtid_slave_pos: Table 'mysql.gtid_slave_pos' doesn't exist in engine, Internal MariaDB error code: 1932
2020-05-19 12:22:33 10 [Note] Master '2020-03-16 14:08:15 0 [Note] Added new Master_info '' to hash table
': Slave I/O thread: Start asynchronous replication to master '@:3306' in log '' at position 4
2020-05-19 12:22:33 10 [ERROR] Master '2020-03-16 14:08:15 0 [Note] Added new Master_info '' to hash table
': Slave I/O: Fatal error: Invalid (empty) username when attempting to connect to the master server. Connection attempt terminated. Internal MariaDB error code: 1593
2020-05-19 12:22:33 10 [Note] Master '2020-03-16 14:08:15 0 [Note] Added new Master_info '' to hash table
': Slave I/O thread killed while connecting to master
2020-05-19 12:22:33 10 [Note] Master '2020-03-16 14:08:15 0 [Note] Added new Master_info '' to hash table
': Slave I/O thread exiting, read up to log 'FIRST', position 4
2020-05-19 12:22:33 7 [Note] Initialized Master_info from 'master-2020@002d03@002d16@002014@003a08@003a15@00200@0020@005bnote@005d@0020c@003a@005cxampp@005cmysql@005cbin@005cmysqld@002eexe@003a@0020ready@0020for@0020connections@002e@000d.info'
2020-05-19 12:22:33 7 [Note] Added new Master_info '2020-03-16 14:08:15 0 [Note] c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
' to hash table
2020-05-19 12:22:33 7 [Note] Started replication for '2020-03-16 14:08:15 0 [Note] c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
'
2020-05-19 12:22:33 13 [Note] Master '2020-03-16 14:08:15 0 [Note] c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
': Slave SQL thread initialized, starting replication in log 'FIRST' at position 0, relay log '.\mysql-relay-bin-2020@002d03@002d16@002014@003a08@003a15@00200@0020@005bnote@005d@0020c@003a@005cxampp@005cmysql@005cbin@005cmysqld@002eexe@003a@0020ready@0020for@0020connections@002e@000d.000001' position: 4
2020-05-19 12:22:33 12 [ERROR] Master '2020-03-16 14:08:15 0 [Note] c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
': Slave I/O: Unable to load replication GTID slave state from mysql.gtid_slave_pos: Table 'mysql.gtid_slave_pos' doesn't exist in engine, Internal MariaDB error code: 1932
2020-05-19 12:22:33 7 [Note] Reading Master_info: 'master-version@003a@0020@002710@002e4@002e6@002dmariadb@0027@0020@0020socket@003a@0020@0027@0027@0020@0020port@003a@00203306@0020@0020mariadb@002eorg@0020binary@0020distribution@000d.info'  Relay_info:'relay-log-version@003a@0020@002710@002e4@002e6@002dmariadb@0027@0020@0020socket@003a@0020@0027@0027@0020@0020port@003a@00203306@0020@0020mariadb@002eorg@0020binary@0020distribution@000d.info'
2020-05-19 12:22:33 13 [ERROR] Master '2020-03-16 14:08:15 0 [Note] c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
': Slave SQL: Unable to load replication GTID slave state from mysql.gtid_slave_pos: Table 'mysql.gtid_slave_pos' doesn't exist in engine, Internal MariaDB error code: 1932
2020-05-19 12:22:33 12 [Note] Master '2020-03-16 14:08:15 0 [Note] c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
': Slave I/O thread: Start asynchronous replication to master '@:3306' in log '' at position 4
2020-05-19 12:22:33 12 [ERROR] Master '2020-03-16 14:08:15 0 [Note] c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
': Slave I/O: Fatal error: Invalid (empty) username when attempting to connect to the master server. Connection attempt terminated. Internal MariaDB error code: 1593
2020-05-19 12:22:33 12 [Note] Master '2020-03-16 14:08:15 0 [Note] c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
': Slave I/O thread killed while connecting to master
2020-05-19 12:22:33 12 [Note] Master '2020-03-16 14:08:15 0 [Note] c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
': Slave I/O thread exiting, read up to log 'FIRST', position 4
2020-05-19 12:22:33 7 [ERROR] Failed to open the relay log '.\mysql-relay-bin-version@003a@0020@002710@002e4@002e6@002dmariadb@0027@0020@0020socket@003a@0020@0027@0027@0020@0020port@003a@00203306@0020@0020mariadb@002eorg@0020binary@0020distribution@000d.000001' (relay_log_pos 4)
2020-05-19 12:22:33 7 [ERROR] Could not find target log during relay log initialization
2020-05-19 12:22:33 7 [ERROR] Initialized Master_info from 'master-version@003a@0020@002710@002e4@002e6@002dmariadb@0027@0020@0020socket@003a@0020@0027@0027@0020@0020port@003a@00203306@0020@0020mariadb@002eorg@0020binary@0020distribution@000d.info' failed
2020-05-19 12:22:33 7 [Note] Added new Master_info 'Version: '10.4.6-MariaDB'  socket: ''  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
' to hash table
2020-05-19 12:22:33 7 [Note] Reading Master_info: 'master-2020@002d03@002d16@002014@003a08@003a15@00200@0020@005bnote@005d@0020innodb@003a@0020buffer@0020pool@0028s@0029@0020load@0020completed@0020at@0020200316@002014@003a08@003a15@000d.info'  Relay_info:'relay-log-2020@002d03@002d16@002014@003a08@003a15@00200@0020@005bnote@005d@0020innodb@003a@0020buffer@0020pool@0028s@0029@0020load@0020completed@0020at@0020200316@002014@003a08@003a15@000d.info'
2020-05-19 12:22:33 7 [Note] Initialized Master_info from 'master-2020@002d03@002d16@002014@003a08@003a15@00200@0020@005bnote@005d@0020innodb@003a@0020buffer@0020pool@0028s@0029@0020load@0020completed@0020at@0020200316@002014@003a08@003a15@000d.info'
2020-05-19 12:22:33 7 [Note] Added new Master_info '2020-03-16 14:08:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200316 14:08:15
' to hash table
2020-05-19 12:22:33 7 [Note] Started replication for '2020-03-16 14:08:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200316 14:08:15
'
2020-05-19 12:22:33 0 [Warning] Reading of some Master_info entries failed
2020-05-19 12:22:33 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize multi master structures
2020-05-19 12:22:33 15 [Note] Master '2020-03-16 14:08:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200316 14:08:15
': Slave SQL thread initialized, starting replication in log 'FIRST' at position 0, relay log '.\mysql-relay-bin-2020@002d03@002d16@002014@003a08@003a15@00200@0020@005bnote@005d@0020innodb@003a@0020buffer@0020pool@0028s@0029@0020load@0020completed@0020at@0020200316@002014@003a08@003a15@000d.000001' position: 4
2020-05-19 12:22:33 0 [ERROR] Aborting
2020-05-19 12:22:33 14 [ERROR] Master '2020-03-16 14:08:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200316 14:08:15
': Slave I/O: Unable to load replication GTID slave state from mysql.gtid_slave_pos: Table 'mysql.gtid_slave_pos' doesn't exist in engine, Internal MariaDB error code: 1932
2020-05-19 12:22:33 15 [ERROR] Master '2020-03-16 14:08:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200316 14:08:15
': Slave SQL: Unable to load replication GTID slave state from mysql.gtid_slave_pos: Table 'mysql.gtid_slave_pos' doesn't exist in engine, Internal MariaDB error code: 1932
2020-05-19 12:22:33 14 [ERROR] Master '2020-03-16 14:08:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200316 14:08:15
': Slave I/O: Fatal error: Invalid (empty) username when attempting to connect to the master server. Connection attempt terminated. Internal MariaDB error code: 1593
```

Trying to read the error log it seems that the problem is kind of different from the ones that most people encounter. I might need to reinstall Xampp but then I'll have to find a way to save my databases and I don't know how that will happen since I can't dump them even through the shell.

Edit / Update: I've installed Xampp on another machine and copied the data folder to it. It broke MySQL on the other machine as well. At this point, I just want to get the databases.

Answer (score 7):

This tip from [mynotebucket.com](https://www.mynotebucket.com/mariadb-abort-due-to-failed-to-initialize-multi-master-structures/) helped me fixing the error:

- rename folder xampp/mysql/data to something else, like data-org
- create a new folder name data
- copy over all the table folders from data-org to data
- copy over my.ini and ibdata1.  My.ini contains configuration information and ibdata1 contains the table definition.
- start MySQL

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately, the question was asked in May and since then I lost all of my data. Maybe someone in the future will benefit from your answer.
P.S. A reminder for everyone - backup your data regularly!

Comment: copying the table folders didn't work for me, but just creating a clean `data` folder and copying the `mysql` folder from `data-org` got mariadb running again.

Comment: Thank you for this. It sorted my issue out quickly.

Answer (score 3):

remove all the `INFO` files from `xampp\mysql\data`, like:

```
master-2021@002d02@002d25@002010@003a32@003a57@00200@0020@005bnote@005d@0020added@0020new@0020master_info@0020@0027@0027@0020to@0020hash@0020table@000d.info
mysql-relay-bin-2021@002d02@002d25@002010@003a32@003a57@00200@0020@005bnote@005d@0020added@0020new@0020master_info@0020@0027@0027@0020to@0020hash@0020table@000d.000001
relay-log-2021@002d02@002d25@002010@003a32@003a57@00200@0020@005bnote@005d@0020d@003a@005cxampp@005cmysql@005cbin@005cmysqld@002eexe@003a@0020ready@0020for@0020connections@002e@000d.info
```